# Slow HttpClient requests to Youtube

Tags: c#, performance, networking

I imagine this is on the edge of what is considered a good question for this forum but I think it's rather interesting and should hopefully yield some cool insight.  Essentially I have a perf problem. I have a code snippet here.

http://pastebin.com/3WHB7V9G

I tried to document it well. Essentially all it does is make a HEAD request to a URL - it eventually redirects to youtube (and it does, in this case it starts out as a redirector on youtube.com itself). Once it gets the final URL, it takes the video ID and uses youtube API to get some data. It doesn't even parse this data at the moment - it's just the HttpClient requests.

To me, this is simple - it should take < 1 second. And subsequent requests often are. However if you do about one a minute you will find that the entire thing takes 3+ seconds very often, and sometimes fails.  Worse, the simple HEAD request to the main youtube site often takes 2-3 seconds. I have tested this on 2 unrelated networks and found the same thing - feel free to validate me on this.

What am I missing here? Are my expectations of performance unreasonable? Is HTTPClient horrible at initiating connections? Am I configuring something incorrectly?  Any insight is much obliged.

Comment: Please let me know if I can provide more data or benchmarks.

Comment: My timing is better: GetYoutubeVideoIDFromUriAsync TTR: 00:00:00.7850011
GetYoutubeDataFromIDAsync TTR: 00:00:00.3930024
Done with GetYoutubeData. Total RTT: 00:00:01.1830035. I ran it several times and never saw 3 or 5 seconds.

Comment: If you believe in problems with `HttpClient` try to open a TCP Connection for yourself and write data manually.

Answer (score 0):

believe my or not,
added some headers in the request header may help.

For example, user-agent , Connection:keep-alive , or Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With (ajax will send this).

You can try different combination to see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not setting user-agents or specific accept headers will leave some servers in a dilemma, the server won't know what language you want the response in, what format you prefer or your user agent which some websites use to render mobile pages.

The more information you make available to it, the less work the server will have on its plate, the other issue (the one we have no control over) is where your request is routed to, if it's routed to a data center which is far away from you, then naturally the request will take longer.

We can overcome this to an extent by setting up some timeouts & retry logic in our code, below I've configured **requests** to **time out after 450ms** and **retry up to 3 times.**

I've also **got rid of the HttpClient**... Yes, it provides a simple interface to make queries but the cons outweigh the benefits once optimisation is in question.

To further optimise our requests, we need to **scale**, we need to make use of **threads**, **in 1 minute 22 seconds** I ran through **2,000 requests** with just **7 timeouts**!

```
void Main()
{   
    const string Youtube        = "youtube.com";
    const string UriRegexPattern = @"v=([^\&]*)";
    const string UriPath         = "/watch";
    const string UriQuery        = "v=";
    const string TestUri         = "https://www.youtube.com/watch/HYE9H_ZUuOI";
    const string ApiUri          = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={0}&key=AIzaSyDWaA2OoArAjQTHqmN6r9XrpHYNkpKGyGw&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status";
    const int    TotalThreads    = 10;
    ConcurrentQueue<string> UriQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        UriQueue.Enqueue(TestUri);
    }

    Thread[] threads = new Thread[TotalThreads];
    for (int i = 0; i < TotalThreads; i++)
    {
        int iCopy = i;
        threads[iCopy] = new Thread(()=>
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            string uri;

            while (UriQueue.TryDequeue(out uri))
            {
                // Locate the final redirect Uri
                Uri finalUri = Http.GetRedirectDestination(new Uri(uri));
                Console.WriteLine ("THREAD[{0}] >>> Time taken locating redirect: {1}", iCopy, sw.Elapsed);
                sw.Reset();

                // Ensure that the host is youtube, and the page contains a video
                if (!finalUri.ContainsHost(Youtube) || !finalUri.ContainsPath(UriPath) || !finalUri.ContainsQuery(UriQuery)) return;

                // Extract the youtubeId using a regular expression.
                string youtubeId = finalUri.ExtractQuery(UriRegexPattern);

                // The uri of api to query including the youtubeId extracted
                string apiUri = string.Format(ApiUri, youtubeId);

                // Reset the stopwatch and query the api
                sw.Start();
                string json = Http.Get(new Uri(apiUri));
                Console.WriteLine ("THREAD[{0}] >>> Time taken querying api:       {1}", iCopy, sw.Elapsed);
                sw.Stop();

                // Also lets try not to get blacklisted by youtube
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        });

        threads[iCopy].Start();
    }

    foreach(var thread in threads)
    {   
        thread.Join();
    }
}

public static class Http
{
    public static Uri GetRedirectDestination(Uri uri, int retries = 0)
    {
        Uri redirectUri = null;
        HttpWebRequest request             = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method                     = "HEAD";
        request.Accept                     = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
        request.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6";
        request.UserAgent                  = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36";
        request.AutomaticDecompression     = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        request.Timeout                    = 450;
        try
        {           
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect || 
                    response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RedirectKeepVerb || 
                    response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RedirectMethod)
                {
                    redirectUri = GetRedirectDestination(new Uri(response.Headers["Location"]));
                }

                return response.ResponseUri;
            }

        }
        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("WebException Uri: {0}", uri);
            Console.WriteLine (">> Message:  {0}", exception.Message);
            Console.WriteLine (">> Status:   {0}", exception.Status);

            if (retries > 2)
            {
                throw;  
            }

            retries += 1;

            return GetRedirectDestination(uri, retries);
        }
    }

    public static string Get(Uri uri, int retries = 0)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request             = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Accept                     = "application/json";
        request.AutomaticDecompression     = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

        try
        {           
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream stream            = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader      = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();  
            }
        }
        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            // throw;
            string exceptionResponse = string.Empty;
            using (Stream stream = exception.Response.GetResponseStream())

            if (retries > 2)
            {
                throw;
            }

            retries += 1;

            return Get(uri, retries); 
        }
    }

}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string text)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text);
    }

    public static bool ContainsHost(this Uri uri, string host)
    {
        if (uri == null)               throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");
        if (host.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) throw new ArgumentNullException("host");

        return uri.Host.Contains(host);
    }

    public static bool ContainsPath(this Uri uri, string path)
    {
        if (uri == null)                           throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");
        if (path.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())             throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
        if (uri.PathAndQuery.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) return false;

        return uri.PathAndQuery.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(path.ToLowerInvariant());
    }

    public static bool ContainsQuery(this Uri uri, string query)
    {   
        if (uri == null)                    throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");
        if (query.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())     throw new ArgumentNullException("query");
        if (uri.Query.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) return false;

        return uri.Query.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(query.ToLowerInvariant());
    }

    public static string ExtractQuery(this Uri uri, string regexPattern)
    {
        if (regexPattern.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) throw new ArgumentNullException("regexPattern");
        if (uri.Query.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())    return null;

        Match match = Regex.Match(uri.Query, regexPattern);
        return match.Groups[1].Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will need some more time to go through everything here but FYI I awarded you the bounty before it expired since you seem to have put a lot of effort and detail here :)

Comment: I have what amounts to your exact code, Get/GetRedirected functions (though with async) and plugged into my system I still get 3-6 second total time. Nuts :(

Comment: @Ben over how many requests? There will always be the case where your calls get directed to a server that's overloaded, or routed to another data center that is located far away by timing out and retrying you have cut down almost 90% of the waiting time. Also is there a reason why you're making them async? They're great for freeing up IIS threads to handle other requests to an ASP.NET website, or not blocking the UI thread if you're playing with WPF, however I wouldn't recommend it for instances such as this .